# Restart browser on error

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer

Is there a way to restart a browser (Internet Explorer, Firefox, etc) automatically upon receiving an error such as a DNS error or Page not found?

Background: It is for a web based signage application that has intermittent network drop outs, therefore if there's no internet, and the sign tries to go to the next page, an error occurs on browser, and we get one big ugly sign. We need a way to either restart the browser, or customise displayed error messages to use javascript to try redirection to the live sign again.

Comment: What language is the application in?  You should be able to handle this within the code.  Check this out for .NET apps - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default error pages pretty easily. You should check out [this page](http://tehpost.blogspot.com/2007/02/how-to-change-firefox-error-message.html) which is a little old but still applies. Basically you have to unzip a jar file and edit the netError.xhtml file. You could toss in a auto redirect. That is for firefox of course. I could not locate IE's counterpart tho sorry.